# Python- unittest why SetUpClass gives attribute error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, python-unittest

I am using unittest and pytest

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
@ddt
class SendformTest(unittest.TestCase):


    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
        self.sf = SendForms(self.driver)
        self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):  ############ I want this method to run just once after login
        self.sf.navigateToCCForms("img")
```

When I try to run this I get an attribute error:

> **AttributeError: type object 'SendformTest' has no attribute 'sf'**

Comment: My guess is that `setUpClass` is running before `classSetup`. Is there a reason you are using both pytest and unittest? It is my understanding that pytest is meant to be used instead of unittest, not in addition to it.

Comment: I have been told that pytest compliments unittest and this is how I learned selenium so never learned to use just one

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not entirely familiar with pytest, a quick google search took me to their page about using [pytest with unittest.TestCase](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html). The note at the bottom states:

> unittest.TestCase methods cannot directly receive fixture function arguments as implementing that is likely to inflict on the ability to run general unittest.TestCase test suites

So my guess is your fixture is never running, leading to your setUp method's failure.